# Create a comma separated list from a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table in R and I want to get the entries of a column in a dataframe to read out in a form of `'a,b,c,d,e'` instead of `[1] a b c d`, as I want to pass it into a sql query for a `WHERE DUMMY IN ('a,b,c,d,e')`

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm guessing I make it a giant string and add a `','` at the end of every `' '` but I was wondering if it maybe a way to simply snag the column in a manner that R automatically reads it in this format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `letters` vector is in-built in R, and `paste0` allows you to "collapse" vectors with specified separation characters, in this case a comma:

```
> paste0(letters[1:5], collapse=",")
[1] "a,b,c,d,e"
```

It wasn't clear what form these letters had in a dataframe, but if they were simply a column named, say `letts`, you could do this:

```
paste0( dfrm$letts, collapse=",")
```

Comment: `toString(letters[1:5])` is a shorthand for this too.

Comment: Well, Ah'll be. Even written by R. Gentleman. It does start out with `string <- paste(x, collapse = ", ")` and I'm noting that the extra space after the comma was not part of the requested result.

Comment: For SQL purposes the white space won't matter, but yes, it is slightly different.

Comment: This is close but I'm getting a result of:  "c(a, b, c, d, \ne, f, g, h, i, \nj, k)" is there a way to drop the c and \n?

Comment: If you put carriage returns in your input stream they will appear as "\n". You need to post full code to help resolve the reason for inclusion of `c` and the carriage returns. Using either my method or that of thelatemail does not produce what you are claiming.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that what you really want is the string `"'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"`.  We can use `shQuote` to quote the elements and `toString` to turn them into a single comma separated string.  Finally insert it into the SQL statement using `sprintf`:

```
lets <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

s <- toString(shQuote(lets))
s
## [1] "'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"

sql <- sprintf("select * from mytab where mycol in (%s)", s)
sql
## [1] "select * from mytab where mycol in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')"
```

You can also use fn$ from the gsubfn package to perform the insertion.  sqldf automatically loads gsubfn so this works using `s` from above:

```
library(sqldf)
fn$sqldf("select 'b' in ($s) as isPresent")
##   isPresent
## 1         1
```

Comment: Behaves the same on a Mac. But I'm wondering if the OP needed the column names individually quoted. It's not what he asked for, but I know you are an acknowledged (at least by me)  SQL-meister.

Comment: Since it works on Mac too I've shortened it to just `shQuote(lets)` and removed Note.  If there were not quotes around the elements then they would be referring to column `a`, column `b`, etc. which seems unlikely.